# Is it possible to store files in browser's temporary folder and retrieve them using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, pdf-generation, browser-cache

I'm using a PDF viewer on the frontend which can only read `.pdf` URLs (it's not able to read blob directly). So I'll need to download those files to the user's computer first. Hypothetically, this is what I want to do:

```js
// download blob
let pdf = fetch(mysite.com);

// store in a temporary folder
// maybe "%AppData%\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Cache"?
browser.storeFile(pdf);

// retrieve the file from temporary folder and pass to PDF viewer
myPDFViewer.load('%AppData%\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Cache\my-file.pdf')
```

The PDF viewer I'm using can load offline files perfectly fine, as long as I have the absolute path to the file (ending with `.pdf`). I have tried all sorts of things but still not able to generate such `.pdf` URLs from the fetched blob.

So, is it possible to download files, store them in a temporary folder internal to the browser (which will get cleaned up automatically), and generate absolute local paths to those files?

Comment: @KJ If I do `var blob = new Blob([data], {type: "application/pdf"})` and then `let pdfURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob)`, I will get a URL that doesn't end with `.pdf`, like `blob:http://localhos:3000/asds343ds`. How do I display that file on the front end? Just removing "blob:" and adding ".pdf" doesn't work (if I paste that link directly into the browser, it downloads the file, which is not what I want). I need a link that ends with `.pdf` so my PDF viewer can read it).